# Order By Upper not sorting correctly after a set number of records get returned

Tags: sql, oracle

The 2 queries below are exactly the same except for the "Not In" condition.

The following query yields a correct sorting of the following names:

**Query:**

```
Select (Bp.Last_Name||', '||Bp.First_Name||' '||Substr(Bp.Middle_Name,1,1)) As Username
From Scrty.User_Account Ua 
Inner Join Buspty.Business_Person Bp On Ua.Business_Person_Uuid = Bp.Business_Party_Uuid And Ua.Active_Flag = 'Y' And Bp.Last_Name Not In (**'a2s','Abdallah','Abnoosi','Abrahamson','Abrams'**) And Ua.Type = 'APPLICATION'
Inner Join Scrty.User_Account_Aaa Uaa On Ua.Uuid = Uaa.User_Account_Uuid 
Left Outer Join Buspty.Business_Organization Bo On Bo.Business_Party_Uuid = Bp.Primary_Department_Uuid 
Left Outer Join Buspty.Business_Org_Type_Domain Botd On Bo.Business_Org_Type_Uuid = Botd.Uuid And  Botd.Code =2 Left Outer Join  Buspty.Network N On  Bp.Primary_Network_Uuid = N.Uuid 
Order By Upper(Username)
```

**Result:**

```
TAYLOR, BRANDON
Taylor, Brandon
```

However, when I exclude one more names in the "Not In" condition, the query results in the lowercase brandon taylor coming first.

**query:**

```
Select (Bp.Last_Name||', '||Bp.First_Name||' '||Substr(Bp.Middle_Name,1,1)) As Username
From Scrty.User_Account Ua 
Inner Join Buspty.Business_Person Bp On Ua.Business_Person_Uuid = Bp.Business_Party_Uuid And Ua.Active_Flag = 'Y' And Bp.Last_Name Not In (**'a2s','Abdallah','Abnoosi','Abrahamson','Abrams','Abruzzo'**) And Ua.Type = 'APPLICATION' 
Inner Join Scrty.User_Account_Aaa Uaa On Ua.Uuid = Uaa.User_Account_Uuid 
Left Outer Join Buspty.Business_Organization Bo On Bo.Business_Party_Uuid = Bp.Primary_Department_Uuid 
Left Outer Join Buspty.Business_Org_Type_Domain Botd On Bo.Business_Org_Type_Uuid = Botd.Uuid And  Botd.Code =2 Left Outer Join  Buspty.Network N On  Bp.Primary_Network_Uuid = N.Uuid 
Order By Upper(Username)
```

**Result:**

```
Taylor, Brandon
TAYLOR, BRANDON
```

Comment: Making the combination unique did the trick. I added Username at the end. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are ordering by identical values and thus the database is free to choose any order it wants. It's essentially as if you had no `order by` at all (this is actually a nice example on how a database changes the sort order based on conditions in the query - another proof that you should never rely on any implicit order in a query result)

To get a consistent sort order you need to include some unique column into the `order by` clause:

```
Order By Upper(Username), Ua.Uuid  -- or whatever makes the combination unique
```

that will guarantee the same sort order if two usernames (uppercased) are the same. You could also include a timestamp value or something else.

Comment: You can even ORDER BY UPPER(USERNAME), USERNAME so that upper and lower are sorted together, but the 'natively' uppercase ones are sorted first within that.